# Session Start and Session End in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax, umbraco7

I am using umbraco 7.0 and I need to add some custom code on application start, session start and session end. As for registering events in umbraco we have to inherit from `Umbraco.Core.ApplicationEventHandler`, I have sone so. But in that we can only override `ApplicationStarted` and not Session related as we can do in Global.asax.

I have seen [Global.asax in Umbraco 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872770/global-asax-in-umbraco-6) but I can not access Session as shown in that answer `if (Session != null && Session.IsNewSession)`, maybe it was umbraco 6 and something changed in umbraco 7.

Any solutions?

Heres the code suggested in mentioned post.

```
public class Global : Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication
{
  public void Init(HttpApplication application)
  {
    application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(application_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    application.EndRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    //application.Error += new EventHandler(Application_Error); // Overriding this below
  }

  protected override void OnApplicationStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnApplicationStarted(sender, e);
    // Your code here
  }

  private void application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      if (Session != null && Session.IsNewSession) // Not working for me
      {
        // Your code here
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
  }

  private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try { UmbracoFunctions.RenderCustomTree(typeof(CustomTree_Manage), "manage"); }
    catch { }
  }

  private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Your code here
  }

  protected new void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Your error handling here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to find the `Session` object from the `sender` that is passed to you as the argument in `PreRequestHandlerExecute`.

```
public class Global : UmbracoApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        var application = this as HttpApplication;
        application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += PreRequestHandlerExecute;
        base.Init();
    }

    private void PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var session = ((UmbracoApplication)sender).Context.Session;
        if (session != null && session.IsNewSession)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to hit even Init() :/

Comment: Do you have `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" Language="C#" %>` in your `Global.asax`?

Comment: `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>`

Comment: That's your problem, it should be `Inherits="Global"` (Global being the name of your class) instead of `Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" `

Comment: **Could not load type 'Global'.** Parse error on `Inherits="Global"`

Comment: You have to include the namespace as well, so Namespace.YourClassName

Comment: Nope, not hitting Init() anyways, but i'm able to hit initialization by writing a startup class inheriting from `ApplicationEventHandler`

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari You are right, just tried it and it wasn't firing for me as well on umbraco v7. Edited the answer to include the working solution for me.

Comment: thanks DZL that worked. but it hit `Init()` and `PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)` 4 times, any idea why this is happening.

Comment: It should hit `Init()` only once, try removing `base.Init()` and see if that helps. `PreRequestHandlerExecute` will execute multiple times, that is normal - it will  be executed for js and css files as well.